# Prevent EF from adding new child objects instead of just association when inserting new parent object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following:

```
    public int CreateExercise(Exercise newExercise) {

        db.Exercises.Add(newExercise);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return newExercise.ExerciseId;
    }
```

Where Exercise is the following:

```
public class Exercise {

    public Exercise() {
        Users = new Collection<User>();
    } 

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "The value cannot exceed 300 characters. ")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
 }
```

When I create a new Exercise, sometimes pre-existing Users come with it, Id included.  Even with an existing `UserId` specified for these `Users`, new `User` entries are getting added here.  I only want to add associations, not new users - I'd imagine EF is smart enough to figure this out?  What am I doing wrong?

I'm just trying to avoid having to loop through all Users attached to a new Exercise, clearing them out before `Add`ing, making sure they exist, adding the exercise, and then adding each individual user, finally calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: How is the `Exercise` instance being created and initialized? EF won't just add related items to a new entity unless something you do causes it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber it's being serialized from the client, along with associated, pre-existing users

Comment: Ahh; I misunderstood you. I don't have it on-hand, but that's a problem with doing the associations like that. You are doing an `Add()`, so unless you tell EF something different, it assumes the whole object graph needs to be added as new items to the database - if those other entities are not under tracking. There's something you do to indicate the related records are not to be added, but simply associated... don't remember offhand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When disconnected entities are reattached they are in Added state by default.

You can change the state after attaching the exercise.

```
public int CreateExercise(Exercise newExercise) {

    db.Exercises.Add(newExercise);

    // set all attached users to unchanged.
    db.ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().ToList().ForEach(p => p.State = EntityState.Unchanged);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return newExercise.ExerciseId;
}
```